# Navigation back color

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have implemented a navigation Controller between VC1 to VC2. and i have changed the navigation Back Button Tittle to My own Custom Tittle using

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Now i want change the Tint Colour Of the Arrow. But when I try doing,its Not Working Why..?

I have tried these samples

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: You can simply do this by setting this in your viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad function.

Comment: @cyph3r can you do at-lease feedback about answer that you get for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar in child View Controller has got this  back button that appears and will take you to Root ViewController. so you can access the navigationBar corresponding to the navigationController and set its tint colour as follows,

**NOTE**: Try adding this code in your viewWillAppear method.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change tint color after this line:
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

If does not work use custom white arrow image for your cust back button.